# Simplifying Boolean expressions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do I go about Simplifying the following Boolean expression: AB(A + B)(C + C)?

I know (A+B) (A+C)= A+BC but C+C is confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

If $+$ is $OR$, then $C + C = C$. If $C = 1$, then $1$ or $1$ is $1$. The same goes for $0$. If $+$ is $XOR$, then $C + C = 0$, as you will either have two $1$'s or two $0$'s.

Comment: So would the simplified boolean expression be A+B=C? since C+C=C

Comment: No. $AB(A + B) = AAB + ABB = AB + AB = AB$. Then $AB(C + C) = ABC$.

Comment: if + is OR is ' NOT? and is * AND?

Comment: Yes. I should have clarified. Sorry.

Comment: no problem I totally get it now. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)